# Haskell Double String Concatenation

Tags: haskell

I am starting out in Haskell and have created the following two functions:

```
calcBmi :: ( RealFloat a ) => a -> a -> a -- Accepts two and returns one 'RealFloat' number.
calcBmi w h = w / h ^ (2 :: Integer) -- Stores argument one and two in w and h respectively and evaluates

outputBmi :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String -- Accepts two RealFloats and returns string
outputBmi weight height = let bmi = calcBmi weight height in "Your BMI was calculated to " ++ bmi
```

When I attempt to compile this code I get the following exception

> Couldn't match expected type '[Char]' with actual type 'a'
>
> In the second argument of '(++)', namely 'bmi'

I am stumped as to what the error even means, nevermind how to fix the code to compile correctly. I can only assume it has something to do with the type of the 'bmi' variable.

If someone could help a beginner out that would be much appreciated. If you see other issues in the code (or if I am using the wrong terminology) feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is not a string, and therefore can not be used by the (++) function.  Usually, you can however convert it to a String using `show`, however, your type doesn't specify that `a` is an instance of class `Show`, so you may have to add this, or even just specify the type directly (ie- `Float`)

For instance, you can change the type of calcBmi

```
calcBmi :: Float->Float->Float
```

or

```
calcBmi :: (RealFloat a, Show a)=>a->a->a
```

Then you can create a string as follows

```
"Your BMI was calculated to " ++ show bmi
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there a reason why `calcBmi :: (RealFloat a, Show b)=>a->a->b` shouldn't be used over your suggestion?

Comment: It also seems that I needed to change `outputBmi :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> String` to `outputBmi :: (RealFloat a, Show a) => a -> a -> String` as well to prevent 'Could not deduce (Show a) arising from a use of `calcBmi'' error. Not sure why, any insight?

Comment: @Harry the signature `(RealFloat a, Show b)=>a->a->b` states that `a` can be chosen to be any floating point type, and `b` can be chosen to be any type which can be converted to string. This would allow the user to choose e.g. `Float -> Float -> (Bool, Int)` as the whole type, which is not what we want. Also, we need to convert to string the argument of type `a`, so we need the constraint `Show a`, not `Show b`.